# Rounding up to the nearest .49 or .99

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want an SQL query to round up to the nearest .49 or .99

I currently have it written to round up to .99 no problems, using the FLOOR or TRUNCATE function

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value=meta_value*1.39
WHERE meta_key='_saleprice' OR meta_key='_price';
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = FLOOR(meta_value) + 0.99
WHERE meta_key='_price' OR meta_key='_saleprice’;
```

this first of all multiplies the price by 1.39
then FLOORS this (removed after the decimal rounding down to nearest whole number) then adds the 0.99 on to the end... Effecitvely in total this rounds up to the nearest 0.99

```
PRICE AFTER *1.39          PRICE AFTER ROUNDING
10.00                                                10.99
10.49                                                10.99
10.50                                                10.99
10.99                                                10.99
11.00                                                11.99
11.49                                                11.99
11.50                                                11.99
11.99                                                11.99
```

what I want to achieve is

```
PRICE AFTER *1.39          PRICE AFTER ROUNDING
10.00                                                10.49
10.49                                                10.49
10.50                                                10.99
10.99                                                10.99
11.00                                                11.49
11.49                                                11.49
11.50                                                11.99
11.99                                                11.99
```

How am I best going about achieving this?

Comment: * 2.0, round up, divide by 2, subtract 0.01

Comment: @jarlh close, and really nice simple maths solution. This works for everything except .00 values which end up being .99 below the original value. 10.00 becomes 9.99 for example.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed...

Comment: What about *2, add 1, round down, divide by 2, subtract 0.01

Comment: * 2.0, trunc down, divide by 2, add 0.49?

Comment: @jarlh YEAH thats neater !! Thanks...

Comment: @Jarlh post an an answer and I will mark as correct if you like !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
* 2.0, trunc down, divide by 2, add 0.49
```

Answer (score 1):

The following appears to work:

```
select ceil(meta_value * 2 + 0.001)/2 - 0.01
```

This is a bit tricky, because 10.50 should be going to 10.99, not 10.49.